# Python3 Running atexit only on the main process

Tags: python-3.x, process, multiprocessing, parent-child, atexit

I have a program that spawns multiple child processes, how would I make the program only call atexit.register(function) on the main process and not on the child processes as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The functions registered via atexit are inherited by the children processes.

The simplest way to prevent that, is via calling atexit after you have spawned the children processes.